# R formula of type y ~ fn(type="x")+fn(type="z"), disregard the second occurence of fn?

Tags: r

I have a model building function where the formula can contain a some functions, and I would like it work so that if user inputs the function several times, only first occasion is used with a warning. For example in `lm` if we use same variable twice, the second one is dropped:

```
y<-1:3
x<-1:3 
lm(y~x+x)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
          0            1
```

This works because the function `terms` used in `model.frame` removes variables with identical name. But in my case I'm working with functions inside of formula which doesn't necessarily have identical argument list, and I would like this behaviour to extend so that arguments of these functions wouldn't matter:

```
model(y~x+fn("x"))
  (Intercept) x temp
1           1 1    1
2           1 2    1
3           1 3    1
model(y~x+fn("x")+fn("x")) #identical function calls
  (Intercept) x temp
1           1 1    1
2           1 2    1
3           1 3    1
model(y~x+fn("x")+fn("z")) #function with different argument value
Error in attr(all_terms, "variables")[[1 + ind_fn]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Here is an example function (highly simplified) I used above:

```
model <- function(formula, data) {    

  #the beginning is pretty much copied from lm function    
  mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)   
  mf <- mf[c(1L,  match(c("formula", "data"), names(mf), 0L))]
  mf[[1L]] <- as.name("model.frame")
  mf$na.action <- as.name("na.pass")  

  all_terms <- if (missing(data)){ 
    terms(formula, "fn")
  } else terms(formula, "fn", data = data)

  #find the position of the function call in the formula
  ind_fn <- attr(all_terms, "specials")$fn

  #update the formula by removing the "fn" part
  if(!is.null(ind_fn)){
    fn_term <- attr(all_terms, "variables")[[1 + ind_fn]]
    formula <- update( formula, paste(". ~ .-", deparse(fn_term, 
                       width.cutoff = 500L, backtick = TRUE)))  
     mf$formula<-formula           
  } 

  # build y and X
  mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())   
  y <- model.response(mf, "numeric")
  mt <- attr(mf, "terms")
  X <- model.matrix(mt, mf)


  #if fn was in formula do something with it
  if (!is.null(ind_fn)){

    foobar<-function(type=c("x","z")){
      if(type=="x"){
        rep(1,nrow(X))
      } else rep(0,nrow(X))
    }
    fn_term[[1]]<-as.name("foobar") 
    temp<-eval(fn_term)
    X<-cbind(X,temp)
  }  

  X
  }
```

I could check the name of the specials (the function calls) and rename them as identical with the first occurence, but I was wondering if there would be more clever way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get your code to work correctly, but assuming I've understood your task, perhaps something like this accomplishes what you're after.

```
f <- y ~ x + fn("x") + fn("z") + z + fn('a')
# get list of terms
vars <- as.list(attr(terms(f), 'variables'))
# get those terms that are duplicate calls
redundant <- vars[sapply(vars, is.call) & duplicated(sapply(vars, function(x) as.list(x)[[1]]))]
# remove the duplicate calls from the formula
update(f, paste(". ~ .", paste(sapply(redundant, deparse), collapse='-'), sep='-'))
# y ~ x + fn("x") + z
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the `is.call` function, this works after checking that `redundant` isn't empty.

Comment: There is one problem with this solution, if the formula is `data[,"y"]~data[,"x1"]+data[,"x2"]`, both explanatory variables are deemed as redundant where neither one should be. Subsetting is also counted as call. Similarly `y~log(x1)+log(x2)` fails.

Comment: Replacing the first condition with this seems to work:`sapply(vars, function(x) c(as.list(x)[[1]])%in%c("fn","fn2"))`.